# Magento 2 how to disable My Requisition Lists from general customer in my account?

Tags: customer-account

I want to display My Requisition Lists only for company and B2B user and want to hide My Requisition Lists from the general customers[B2C] from my account section. How can I get this functionality in Magento2.3.4?

[image: Want to remove for guest user]

Answer (score 0):

1.- On the Admin sidebar, go to **Stores** > **Settings** > **Configuration**.

If you have a multisite installation, set the Store View control in the upper-left corner to the website where the configuration applies.

2.- In the left panel under General, choose B2B Features and disable it.

More info: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/b2b-features.html#configure-b2b-features